# Why is the default export option .ear for my recently imported maven project

Tags: eclipse, ear

So I have here an empty Eclipse, right? It empty!

[image]

Now I've imported my maven project. It's POM says it should be packaged as a .jar

[image]

However the default export action is to .ear, dear friends!

[image]

What is happening?

I thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry about your question re. Latin corpus and other NLP resources for the Latin language.  I think the question was very legitimate for the site and was about to upvote it and post this remark...
Wow! `Why the close and down votes?`  This is a very appropriate question for StackOverflow.  Labelled corpora and other forms of [Natural] language-specific supporting resources are intrinsic parts of tools used by programmers in the field of NLP.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably counter intuitive, but you should use Run As... / Maven package (or install) menu.